# Kalman filtering confusion

Tags: kalman-filter

Say I have a very simple model

\begin{align}
&C_t = C_{t-1} + z_t\\
&X_t = C_t + v_t
\end{align}

everything is 1-dimensional, $z_t$ and $v_t$ are are uncorrelated and white noises, and $X_t$ is the observed value.

I generate a simulated data sequence with some predefined paramenter for variance, then I use Kalman filter with the same parameter to do the filtering.

Then I check the output $C_t$, it doesn't look like anything like random walk, $dC_t = C_t - C_{t-1}$ are serially correlated. What do I miss here? Or rather, is the filtered sequence necessarily satisfy model assumption?

The following matlab code implement the algorithm

```
verror = 2;
vobjs = 3;
N = 10000;
x = randn(1,N)*sqrt(verror);
n = randn(1,N)*sqrt(vobjs);
obs = cumsum(x) + n;
%plot(obs)
filtered = zeros(size(x));

filtered(1) = 0;
s0 = verror;
for i = 2 : N
    Kgain = (s0+verror)/(s0+vobjs+verror);
    filtered(i) = (1-Kgain)*filtered(i-1) + Kgain*(obs(i));
    s0 = (1-Kgain)*(s0+verror);
end
var(diff(filtered(1000:end)))
var(filtered(1000:end) - obs(1000:end))
% The filtered sequence is 0 auto-correlated.
autocorr(filtered(1000:end) - obs(1000:end))
```

The code is now fixed. there is no auto-correlation. What about variance? The variances are 2.0226 and 1.3694 respectively.

Comment: When you say you "check the output $C_t$...", do you mean the *filtered estimates* $\hat C_{t|t}$, not the *true states $C_t$? What values for the two variances did you use?

Comment: yes, filtered output.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example and/or plot? The increments $\Delta_t = \hat{C}_{t|t} - \hat{C}_{t-1|t-1}$ of the state estimates *are* uncorrelated in this case.

Comment: @cardinal, why the values of the two variances matter? The state variable increment is still uncorrelated, no?

Comment: No, they don't matter for the result. But, I wanted to know so I could try to reproduce what you were observing, in case a small sample was maliciously conspiring with idiosyncratic choices for the variances to produce some apparent correlation. :-)

Comment: Apparently, the variance does matter, if I choose observation error > state error, I got negative auto-correlation, if I choose observation error < state error, I got positive auto-correlation.

Comment: You have mixed up `vobjs` and `verror` in both the Kalman-gain calculation and the update to `s0`. Review the Kalman recursions carefully; it should be: `Kgain = (s0 + verror)/(s0 + verror + vobjs)` and `s0 = (1-Kgain)*(s0 + verror)`.

Comment: you are right. Is the following station correct, if Kalman filter indeed the true model, the filtered sequence and induced observation error should have the model statistic property.

Comment: Seems like the issue the question originally was about is fixed, and now the only question in the question seems to be "What about variance" which is unclear.